# Slow WHERE IN SQL query using pandas python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas, where-in

I am trying to speed up a sqlite3 query, currently it is quite slow.

I have a table of ~22 million rows with two columns (uid, info)

In python, I then find a list of ~10,000 uid values that correspond to uid's in the table above.
(randomly generated numbers for this post)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')

uids = np.random.random(10000)
uids = list(map(int,list(map(round,uids*2000000))))

sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE uid IN (' + ','.join(map(str, uids)) + ')'
sqlpd = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,conn)
```

The query works, but it is quite slow (~15 seconds). Wondering how I can speed this up, I am guessing it is the WHERE ... IN methodology that is causing the issue

Comment: random idea: try creating a temporary table with the uids you need and join with `mytable` - it would help in case that `IN` is implemented with a `O(n*m)` algorithm with n rows and m uids, but join would be already optimized

Comment: idea #2: run 10000 selects `WHERE uid = {}` - both ideas are possible to implement in `O(m*log(n))`, no idea which is faster

Comment: Is the uid column indexed?

Comment: I'd also create a temp table in SQLite and make a join. __IMO__ `idea #2` is going to be painfully slow...

Comment: The uid column is the primary index

Comment: Tried both your suggestions @Aprillion , neither improved speed. Any other suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but I dropped the table and rebuilt with the same code/data. Now it is running in 0.1 seconds.

Problem solved, not sure why :/

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [@Aprillion's idea #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183000/slow-where-in-sql-query-using-pandas-python#comment79328841_46183000):

```
pd.DataFrame({'uid':uids}).to_sql('tmp', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')
```

now we can do this:

```
sql_query = 'SELECT a.* FROM mytable a JOIN tmp b ON a.uid = b.uid'
sqlpd = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query,conn)
```

Comment: Tried this solution, unfortunately no improvement. Took almost exactly the same time as my previous attempt (~15 seconds).